# How to cycle through FULL RGB spectrum smoothly

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to cycle through the RGB spectrum smoothly, but so far I've only been able to make code that either goes through 768 colors (256*3) smoothly or goes through 16777216 colors (256^3) with discrete jumps.

Here's the code that runs smoothly:

```
void loop() { 
  setColor(255,0,0);
  setColor(255,255,0);
  setColor(0,255,0);
  setColor(0,255,255);
  setColor(0,0,255);
  setColor(255,0,255);
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
  while ( r != red ) {
    if ( r < red ) r += 1;
    if ( r > red ) r -= 1;
    _setColor();
    delay(10);
  }
  while ( g != green){
    if ( g < green ) g += 1;
    if ( g > green ) g -= 1;
    _setColor();
    delay(10);
  }
  while ( b != blue){
    if ( b < blue ) b += 1;
    if ( b > blue ) b -= 1;
    _setColor();
    delay(10);
  }
}


void _setColor() {
  analogWrite(redPin, r);
  analogWrite(greenPin, g);
  analogWrite(bluePin, b); 
}
```

Here's the code that runs through every RGB value:

```
void loop() { 
  for (r = 0; r <= 255; r++) {
    for (g = 0; g <= 255; g++) {
      for (b = 0; b <= 255; ++) {
        analogWrite(redPin, r);
        analogWrite(greenPin, g);
        analogWrite(bluePin, b); 
      }
    }
}
```

The smooth code will never combine values in between the max/min of the colors, i.e. I never get anything like [128,64,72], only outputs like [255,64,0] or [0,0,72].

The discrete code runs through every blue value, then increases the green value, and starts back at 0 for blue, i.e. [0,0,254] -> [0,0,255] -> [0,1,0] -> [0,1,1] which creates discrete jumps.

I'm trying to get a smooth cycle which goes through every possible RGB value, is that even possible?

Comment: Since the color space is in three dimensions if you just want to go through all the values you could use a Hilbert curve, for example. Might not look that great. It depends on why you want to go through them all and how.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can visit every point in a 256^3 space continuously.

The easiest way is to start with a line, then turn a line into a plane, then turn a plane into a cube.

```
struct simple_generator {
  int current = 0;
  int min = 0;
  int max = 255;
  int direction = 1;
  bool advance() // returns false iff we hit the end
  {
    if (current + direction > max || current+direction < min) {
      direction = -direction;
      return false;
    }
    current += direction;
    return true;
   }
 };
```

now let's make a generator from this.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct shape_generator {
  simple_generator state[N];
  int operator[](std::size_t i) const { return state[i].current; }
  bool advance() {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      if (state[i].advance())
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

now what this does it advances the first simple generator until it overflows (which causes the generator stand still and reverse directions).  If it overflows, it "recursively" advances the next one.

If every generator overflows, it returns false.  Otherwise it returns true.

This will generate a pretty boring curve, as it mostly looks like "blue goes to top, then back down, back to top, and back down".  Only after many cycles does any green show up.  And only after many cycles of green does any red show up.

A fancier one would use an approximation of a real space-filling curve, like the Hilbert curve.  But that should work

[Live example with a max of 5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c48eb993ff617b97), because running it for 256^3 elements seems rude.